# Mocking Factory and verifying that methods were called on returned types

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, factory

Lets say I have this service:

```cs
public class Service
{
   ... 

  public Service(IFactory factory)
  {
      ...
  }

  public void Method() 
  {
      IInsatnce instance1 = factory.CreateInstance(params1);
      IInstance instance2 = factory.CreateInstance(params2);

      instance1.CallMethod1();
      instance2.CallMethod2();
  }      
}
```

I want to verify in tests that the methods on those created instances were called. As far as I am unserstanding I have to create mock of the factory which will be returning mock instances. But then, should I keep references on all instances of mocks that will be created in `Method()` and use them to verify methods calles? Is it the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty common use case. Yes, you must return mocks from mocked factory and then do the verification on that mocks. Here using [mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito) syntax:

```
IInstance instanceMock1 = mock(IInstance.class);
IInstance instanceMock2 = mock(IInstance.class);
IFactory factoryMock = mock(IFactory.class);

given(factoryMock(params1)).willReturn(instanceMock1);
given(factoryMock(params2)).willReturn(instanceMock2);

//...
verify(instanceMock1).CallMethod1();
verify(instanceMock2).CallMethod2();
```